# finishActivity(int) does not finish activity or call finishActivityFromChild(activity, int)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, back-stack

I have an activity stack that looks like the following :

A -> B -> C

Upon some action in C, I want to create a new intent and add activity D to the backstack. But in doing so I also want to close activities B and C so that the stack changes to the following :

A -> D

I have played around with NEW_TASKs and CLEAR_TASKs/CLEAR_TOP but none of them seem to work like I'd expect them to (according to documentation).

I found finishActivity(int) and thought I could use it to close B and C if I start them with a requestCode as such in activity A to B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, IntentHelper.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_GROUP_BC);
```

and as such in B to C

```
Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, IntentHelper.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_GROUP_BC);
```

Then in activity C, I would start activity D intent, finishActivity group BC and finish activity C.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(C.this, D.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, IntentHelper.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_GROUP_D);
finishActivity(IntentHelper.INTENT_REQUEST_CODE_GROUP_BC);
finish();
```

When I check my activity stack after doing this though, I do not see group BC activities being finished at all (except for the finished C from the last finish() call). I also do not see finishActivityFromChild(activity, int) being called in the activities that were suppose to finish.

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Comment: Hi did you found a way?